# How to?: If string contains uppercase ''X'' print("X spotted!")

Tags: python, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm working on a school assignment and it works (so far) but I don't understand why I had to put the second `if` statement after `else` in the `tester` function for that `if p` condition (`Xavier`) to work.

1. I need someone to explain why I couldn't use the `if` before `else` in this case.
2. The same condition. It actually needs to test if the user input contains an uppercase X. I have searched online but just can't figure out which method to use.

   ```
    def tester(p, givenstring = "Too short"):    
        result=len(p)
        if result>=10:
            print(p)
        else:
            print(givenstring)
        if p == "Is Xavier here?":  # if p == "X" doesn't work.
            print("X is spotted!")

    def main():
        while True:
            prompt=input("Write something (quit ends): ")
            if prompt=="quit":
                break
            else:
                tester(prompt)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```

Comment: What do you mean by "why I couldn't use the `if` before `else`"? You *are* using an `if` before `else`.

Comment: I have an if after the else. I thought I needed to put if, elif, else in that order. But for me, it wouldn't work until I put if p == after the else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def tester(p, givenstring = "Too short"):    
    result=len(p)
    if result>=10:
        print(p)
    else:
        print(givenstring)
    #Comments should be created using hash(#) not (//) >> //if p == "X" doesn't work.
    if p == "Is Xavier here?":    # this is doing an exact match of the string and not finding 'X'          
        print("X is spotted!")
```

```
def tester(p, givenstring = "Too short"):    
    result=len(p)
    if result>=10:
        print(p)
    else:
        print(givenstring)
    if 'X' in p: # this will return True if 'X' is present in p
        print("X is spotted!")

def main():
    while True:
        prompt=input("Write something (quit ends): ")
        if prompt=="quit":
            break
        else:
            tester(prompt)
main()
```

```
Write something (quit ends): This is captain x-merica
This is captain x-merica
Write something (quit ends): This is captain X-merica
This is captain X-merica
X is spotted!
Write something (quit ends): quit
```

Comment: Amazingly simple. Thank you sir!